# mysql stored procedure to update data based on another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that will allow me to update the shelfprice from one table with the shelfprice of another table based on the liquorcode. But I'm new to mysql and can't seam to figure it out. With the code bellow I keep getting error code 1172. How would I accomplish this?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Test_scheduler`()
BEGIN
DECLARE CodeOld INT DEFAULT 0; DECLARE CodeNew INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE NewPrice DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00; DECLARE OldPrice DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0.00;
SELECT LiquorCode INTO CodeOld FROM liquor_liquor;
SELECT LiquorCode INTO CodeNew FROM liquor_update;
SELECT ShelfPrice INTO NewPrice FROM liquor_update;
SELECT ShelfPrice INTO OldPrice FROM liquor_liquor;

WHILE CodeOld = CodeNew DO
SET OldPrice = NewPrice;
END WHILE;



END
```

Comment: you should have just one `DECLARE` statement, then al the variables then the `BEGIN` statement. Also, this code doesn't update anything, just the variable you create.

Comment: You're getting that error because you are trying to put multiple values into the variables which can only hold one value. I think your approach is wrong, can you edit your question to include the table structures and some test data?